# Stored procedure WHERE dynamically checking if param NAME is null OR has value

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, where-clause

What is the most efficient way to create a dynamic sp where im checking the param NAME either its null or has value. 
my **GOAL** here is to select the specific **name** and their datas **else** just display all name with datas if param **NAME** is null or has no value submitted.
Here's my 2 solution:

**option 1**

```
IF (SELECT call_transactions.`called_name` IS NULL FROM call_transactions) THEN
    SELECT a.`called_name` , DATE_FORMAT(a.`start_datetime`,"%m/%d/%Y %T") AS start_datetime , DATE_FORMAT(a.`end_datetime`,"%m/%d/%Y %T") AS end_datetime, SEC_TO_TIME(a.`duration`) AS duration
    FROM call_transactions a
    WHERE a.`user_id` = pUSERID AND a.duration <> 0 AND DATE_FORMAT(a.start_datetime , "%m/%d/%Y") BETWEEN pSTART AND pEND
    ORDER BY a.start_datetime DESC;
ELSE
    SELECT a.`called_name` , DATE_FORMAT(a.`start_datetime`,"%m/%d/%Y %T") AS start_datetime , DATE_FORMAT(a.`end_datetime`,"%m/%d/%Y %T") AS end_datetime, SEC_TO_TIME(a.`duration`) AS duration
    FROM call_transactions a
    WHERE a.`user_id` = pUSERID AND a.called_name = pNAME AND a.duration <> 0 AND DATE_FORMAT(a.start_datetime , "%m/%d/%Y") BETWEEN pSTART AND pEND
    ORDER BY a.start_datetime DESC;
END IF;
```

**option 2**

```
SELECT a.`called_name` , DATE_FORMAT(a.`start_datetime`,"%m/%d/%Y %T") AS start_datetime , DATE_FORMAT(a.`end_datetime`,"%m/%d/%Y %T") AS end_datetime, SEC_TO_TIME(a.`duration`) AS duration
FROM call_transactions a
WHERE a.`user_id` = pUSERID AND (a.called_name = pNAME OR pNAME = '') AND a.duration <> 0 AND DATE_FORMAT(a.start_datetime , "%m/%d/%Y") BETWEEN pSTART AND pEND
ORDER BY a.start_datetime DESC;
```

Thank you in advance for the enlightenment guys. Just a curious kid here

Comment: You may want to read up on `NULL` vs `''`.  They are not interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Use your 2nd option, but test for the correct value.

```
WHERE a.`user_id` = pUSERID 
  AND (pNAME IS NULL OR a.called_name = pNAME) 
  AND a.duration <> 0 AND DATE_FORMAT(a.start_datetime , "%m/%d/%Y") BETWEEN pSTART AND pEND
```

In the second condition, note that I reversed the terms.

This is not strictly necessary, because the optimizer should prune away whichever condition is unnecessary, but this makes your short-circuit intentions clear.

Note also that `NULL` is not equivalent to empty string, and nothing is equal to `NULL`, so `IS NULL` should be used if NULL is what you are matching against.

I don't know what you're doing with `DATE_FORMAT()` here, but don't do that.

Use correct datetimes everywhere, or use `STR_TO_DATE()` to convert the parameters, not `DATE_FORMAT()` against the column.  You can't compare mm/dd/yyyy "between" two values.  That doesn't make sense.  12/09/2010 is "between" 12/08/2017 and 12/10/2017 because your code is comparing strings, lexcally, not comparing dates.

As a rule, you should never use a column as an argument to function in `WHERE` because this defeats any indexes on the column and forces a full scan.

Comment: Thank you for the solution sir yet I still didn't get all the data if pNAME IS NULL. I'm using DATE_FORMAT() just to easily get my input as is in the db and comparing 2 dates to get data that are inside of those dates.